# How to add validation into textarea for min 250 and max 1000 word count?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am trying to add jquery validation in text area field for min 250 word and max 1000 words. And also display word count in span tag next to text area. Also I also how can I validation of if user copy paste into text area then also this validation should works. Any help and suggestion should be appreciated.

```js
var maxWords = 1000;
var minWords = 250;

$(document).on('keypress', 'textarea[name="writ"]', function(e) {
  var $this, wordcount;

  $this = $(this);
  wordcount = $this.val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
  if (wordcount > maxWords) {
    $('.writing_erorr').text("You've reached the maximum allowed words 1000.");
    return false;
  } else {
    return $('#writing span').text('Total words: ' + wordcount);
  }
});

$("textarea[name='writ']").bind('paste', function(e) {
  // access the clipboard using the api
  var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
  alert(pastedData);
  var $this, wordcount;

  $this = $(this);
  wordcount = $this.val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;
  if (wordcount > maxWords) {
    $('.writing_erorr').text("You've reached the maximum allowed words 1000.");
    return false;
  } else {
    return $('#writing span').text('Total words: ' + wordcount);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=writing class=cond>
    <label class="required">Writing Entry</label>
    <textarea name=writ placeholder="Writing Entries: 100 words min, 600 words max"></textarea>
    <span></span>
    <div class="writing_erorr"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below works as requested, I've added some attributes to the text areas so that you can have multiple text areas on a single page, all with different limits.

You need to add the following attributes `word-limit="true"`, `max-words='n'`, `min-words='n'`. No placeholder is needed anymore because the code automatically generates one after page load.

It is a little more involved that your example, but allows you to do more (not sure what your overall project is).

---

## Word Count

The basic code to do a word count is as follows:

```
wordCount = $.trim( $("#writing").val() ).split(/\s+/).filter(Boolean).length;
```

**Explaination of the code:**

- `$("#writing").val()` - gets the value of the textarea (i.e. the string)
- `.trim()` removes any whitespace at the start or end of the string
- `.split(/\s+/)` divides the string around every space and puts them into an array
- `.filter(Boolean)` skips any blank values in the array - i.e. those created by double spacing
- `.length` gets the length of the array (i.e. how many words there are)

---

## Demo

```js
// Cycle through each textarea and add placeholder with individual word limits
$("textarea[word-limit=true]").each(function() {
  $(this).attr("placeholder", "Writing entries: " + $(this).attr("min-words") + " words min, " + $(this).attr("max-words") + " words max");
});


// Add event trigger for change to textareas with limit
$(document).on("input", "textarea[word-limit=true]", function() {


  // Get individual limits
  thisMin = parseInt($(this).attr("min-words"));
  thisMax = parseInt($(this).attr("max-words"));

  // Create array of words, skipping the blanks
  var removedBlanks = [];
  removedBlanks = $(this).val().split(/\s+/).filter(Boolean);
  
  // Get word count
  var wordCount = removedBlanks.length;
 
  // Remove extra words from string if over word limit
  if (wordCount > thisMax) {
        
      // Trim string, use slice to get the first 'n' values
      var trimmed = removedBlanks.slice(0, thisMax ).join(" ");
      
      // Add space to ensure further typing attempts to add a new word (rather than adding to penultimate word)
      $(this).val(trimmed + " ");
      
    }
    
 
  // Compare word count to limits and print message as appropriate
  if ( wordCount < thisMin) {
  
    $(this).parent().children(".writing_error").text("Word count under " + thisMin + ".");
  
  } else if (wordCount > thisMax) {

    $(this).parent().children(".writing_error").text("Word count over " + thisMax + ".");
  
  } else {
    
    // No issues, remove warning message
    $(this).parent().children(".writing_error").text("");

  }

});
```

```css
.writing_error {
  color: red;
}

[id^=writing] {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

label {
  width: 100%;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=writing1 class=cond>
  <label class="required">Writing Entry 1</label>
  <textarea name=writ word-limit="true" max-words="600" min-words="100"></textarea>
  <span></span>
  <div class="writing_error"></div>
</div>


<div id=writing2 class=cond>
  <label class="required">Writing Entry 2</label>
  <textarea name=writ></textarea>
  <span></span>
  <div class="writing_error"></div>
</div>

<div id=writing3 class=cond>
  <label class="required">Writing Entry 3</label>
  <textarea name=writ word-limit="true" max-words="10" min-words="4"></textarea>
  <span></span>
  <div class="writing_error"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have single textarea in page/form. Can i prevent user to not enter or copy/paste content if they have reach limit (1000 words).

Comment: Update for this request

Answer (score 0):

in your javascript:

```
$('textarea#message_area').on('keyup',function() 
{
  var maxlen = $(this).attr('maxlength');

  var length = $(this).val().length;
  if(length > (maxlen-10) ){
    $('#textarea_message').text('max length '+maxlen+' characters only!')
  }
  else
    {
      $('#textarea_message').text('');
    }
});
```

element:

```
<form>
  <label for="message_area">No more than 100 characters</label>
  <p>
  <textarea id="message_area" maxlength="100" rows="6" cols="70"></textarea>
  </p>
  <span class="hint" id="textarea_message"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: I need to count words not character. Based on min 250 and max 1000 words want to display error message. If user copy paste content then how can i make this validation also works?